# MERN App: Redux store disappears on refresh for some but not all of my components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, crud, mern

**ISSUE** (edited to add store.js and express routes)

I can access and refresh Tournaments.All component because the state doesn't break on page refresh, but the component that displays a single Tournament breaks when I refresh the page or type the URL directly (it ONLY works when I access it via button/link)

**EXPLANATION**

My app has two models: Tournament and User.

Each one has two components: Index (shows all) and Show (shows one)

My app state tree looks like:

```
>tournament
  tournaments: [],
  showTournament: "",
  loading: false
>player
  players: [],
  showPlayer: "",
  loading: false
```

Tournament Index works.  Component renders and displays everything.  I can access it via Link or URL and I can refresh the page without breaking anything.

I'll place the code for tourney Index and Show together below (including Loading since that occurs right before the data loads)

*Store*

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

export default store;
```

*BackEnd Express Routes*

```
// @route   GET /tournaments
// @descrip Get All, INDEX
// @access  Public
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Tournament.find()
        .sort({ date: -1 })
        .then(tournaments => res.json(tournaments))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

// @route   SHOW /tournaments/:id
// @descrip Display a single tournament
// @access  Public
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(tournament => res.json(tournament))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

*Reducer*

```
const initialState = {
  tournaments: [],
  showTournament: "",
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_TOURNAMENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        tournaments: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };

    case SHOW_TOURNAMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        showTournament: state.tournaments.find(tournament => tournament._id === action.payload),
        loading: false
      };

    case TOURNAMENTS_LOADING:
    case TOURNAMENT_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
  };
};
```

*Actions*

```
// Tournament Index
export const getTournaments = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: TOURNAMENTS_LOADING });

  axios
    .get('/tournaments')
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: GET_TOURNAMENTS,
      payload: res.data
    }))
    .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};


// Tournament Show
export const showTournament = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: TOURNAMENT_LOADING });

  axios
    .get(`/tournaments/${id}`)
    .then(() => dispatch({
      type: SHOW_TOURNAMENT,
      payload: id
    }))
    .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};
```

*Index Component*

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Jumbotron, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { InProgress, ResultsPopover } from './buttons';
import { getTournaments, deleteTournament } from '../../actions/tournamentActions';
import TournamentDescription from './descriptions';
import DeleteModal from '../delete/DeleteModal';

class TournamentIndex extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getTournaments();
    };

    static propTypes = {
        getTournaments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    onDelete(id) {
        this.props.deleteTournament(id);
    };

    render() {
        const { tournaments } = this.props.tournament;
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;

        return tournaments.map(({ _id, title, hostedBy, status }) => {
            return (
                <Jumbotron key={_id} className={title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')}>
                    <h1 className="mb-5 text-center">
                        { title }
                        <p style={{fontSize: '0.6em'}} className="text-muted">Hosted by: { hostedBy }</p>
                    </h1>
                    <h4>
                        <TournamentDescription key={_id} title={title} />
                    </h4>
                    <hr className="my-4"/>
                    {
                        isAuthenticated && user.username === hostedBy ?
                            <Fragment>
                                <DeleteModal 
                                    page={"Tournament Index"} 
                                    title={"Delete Tournament"} 
                                    onClick={() => this.onDelete(_id)} 
                                />
                            </Fragment> 
                        :
                        null
                    }
                    <Link 
                        to={ status === "Open" ? `/tournaments/${_id}` : `/tournaments/${_id}/start` } 
                        className="remove-underline"
                    >
                        <Button color="secondary" outline block className="mt-2">
                            <b className="enter-btn">Enter</b>
                        </Button>
                    </Link>
                    { status === "Closed" ? <InProgress /> : null }
                    { status === "Complete" ? <ResultsPopover /> : null }
                </Jumbotron>
            );
        });
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tournament: state.tournament,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTournaments, deleteTournament })(TournamentIndex);
```

*Show Component*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TournamentDescription from './descriptions';
import { showTournament, addParticipant, updateTournamentStatus } from '../../actions/tournamentActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { TournamentSignUp, StartTournament } from './buttons';
import { Button, Spinner } from 'reactstrap';

class TournamentShow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this);
        this.onStartTournament = this.onStartTournament.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.props.showTournament(id);
    };

    static propTypes = {
        tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    onSignUp(tournamentId, user) {
        this.props.addParticipant(tournamentId, user);
    };

    onStartTournament(tourneyId, tourneyParticipants) {
        this.props.updateTournamentStatus(tourneyId, tourneyParticipants);
    };

    render() {
        const { _id, title, hostedBy, status, participants } = this.props.tournament.showTournament;
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;

        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.tournament.loading ?
                    <Spinner color="light" /> :
                    <div style={{color: "lightgrey"}}>
                        <h1 className="text-center">
                            { title }
                            <span style={{fontSize: "0.5em"}}> by { hostedBy }</span>
                        </h1>
                        <h3>
                            <TournamentDescription key={_id} title={ title } />
                        </h3>
                        <br />
                        <p className="text-center" style={{color: "#56A8CBFF", fontSize: "2em"}}>
                            ~ { status } for registration ~
                        </p>
                        <h4 className="text-left mt-5">
                            {
                                participants && participants.length === 1 ? 
                                `${participants && participants.length} Registered Fighter` : 
                                `${participants && participants.length} Registered Fighters`
                            }
                        </h4>
                        <ul>
                            {
                                participants && participants.map(participant => (
                                    <li key={participant._id} className="text-left" style={{fontSize: "1.1em"}}>{participant.username}</li>
                                ))
                            }
                        </ul>
                        {
                            isAuthenticated ?
                            <div>
                                <TournamentSignUp
                                    participants={participants}
                                    userId={user._id}
                                    onClick={() => this.onSignUp(_id, user)} 
                                />
                            </div> :
                            <Button block disabled>Log in to sign up for this tournament</Button>
                        }
                        {
                            isAuthenticated && user.username === hostedBy ?
                            <div>
                                <StartTournament
                                    participants={participants}
                                    onClick={() => this.onStartTournament(_id, participants)}
                                />
                            </div> :
                            null
                        }
                    </div>
                }
                <br /><Link to="/">Back to Tournaments main page</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tournament: state.tournament,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { showTournament, addParticipant, updateTournamentStatus })(TournamentShow);
```

**SUMMARY**

Index works.  I can view all tournaments, refresh the page and access it via URL.

Show does not. I can only access it within the app, but it breaks if I type the URL or refresh the page.

State Tree when I access Show from within the App:

```
tournament
  tournaments: [...],
  showTournament: {...},
  loading: false
```

State Tree when I type the URL or refresh the page:

```
tournament
  tournaments: [],
  loading: false
```

It clears `tournaments` completely, and actually removes `showTournament`

One solution I found was to implement a loading spinner, which I did, but that didn't change the State behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Unless your store is persistent (localStorage, re-retrieved from a DB, etc.) if you refresh or reload the page, it being gone is exactly what I'd expect--that's what a page refresh/reload does, it refreshes/reloads the page.

Comment: Well why doesn't that take place with my Index actions?
Refreshing any of those pages doesn't remove my Store/State (pulls from mongo DB).
Somehow the way I implemented Show is breaking it.  I have been trying to persist the state the same way but I'm having trouble

Comment: Your tournament index appears to make an axios call--no data is *persisted*, it's *retrieved*. When you reload a page that page is *gone*. If you want data to persist across page loads then you need to *keep* it somewhere. This is just how browsers work.

Comment: Hmm. Tournament show is making an axios call too.  So ok, it's not persisting, but it isn't retrieving right either.
Tournament Show is only retrieving if I visit the page via the app, but wouldn't refreshing re-render the component? Which should call componentDidMount() to retrieve the data again?

Comment: I think I just figured it out.  Perhaps I can send an axios POST request first to send that `showTournament` object to the DB, and then retrieve that.  Then, whichever tournament I wanna view will do that.

Comment: Oh but.. if multiple people are viewing tournaments, the database `showTournament` object will constantly be switching.. gah!

Comment: Again: if you want the data persisted locally, persist it locally. If all you need are some IDs it doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: As in localStorage? I can give that a shot..

Comment: How is storing the ID of something already exposed to the client and user a security issue? You might want to consider taking a quick step back, figure out the general browser workflow (e.g., when things are loaded, how, what's the JS context on a new page, etc), and come at this again.